# Lava script game logic to move and teleport back

Tags: lua, roblox

I made this script in my game and its supposed to move a chunk of lava down and then teleport back up when the lava reaches the bottom

Lava Code:

```lua
local part = script.Parent
local bottom = workspace.bottom
wait(5)

while wait(0) do
    part.Position -= Vector3.new(0,1,0)
end

function reset(part)
    part.Position = Vector3.new(-100.412, 102.5, -8.321)
end

bottom.Touched:Connect(reset)
```

Comment: instead of going back up to the top the lava just keeps moving untill it disapears

Answer (score 2):

So the reason why the lava keeps moving down is because the bottom.Touched will not actually function. This is because of the `while loop`. The rest of your code never actually gets triggered until the while loop completes which it never will.

```lua
local part = script.Parent
local bottom = workspace.bottom
wait(5)

while wait(0) do
    part.Position -= Vector3.new(0,1,0)
end
----------------------------------------------
print("Nothing below will be printed")

function reset(part)
    part.Position = Vector3.new(-100.412, 102.5, -8.321)
end
bottom.Touched:Connect(reset)
```

---

In order to fix this, you can move the bottom.Touched connection above the loop

```lua
local part = script.Parent
local bottom = workspace.bottom
wait(5)

function reset(part)
    part.Position = Vector3.new(-100.412, 102.5, -8.321)
end
bottom.Touched:Connect(reset)

while wait(0) do
    part.Position -= Vector3.new(0,1,0)
end
```